# Prevent object modification when a property value of a property grid is changed

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, propertygrid

I inherited the **FileSystemInfo** class to implement a class with name **ShortcutFileInfo** that will represent a shortcut (.lnk) file.

And I'm representing the class through a property grid (Windows Forms project), like this:

[image]

Now, because my implementation works like a common instance of a **FileInfo** object, in the meaning that when any of the properties is set, the setter modifies the file contents, like for example when setting this property to change the file attributes:

```
<Description("The file attributes of the current shortcut file.")>
<DisplayName("Attributes")>
<Category("File Info Extended")>
Public Shadows Property Attributes As FileAttributes
    Get
        Return MyBase.Attributes
    End Get
    Set(value As FileAttributes)
        If (value <> MyBase.Attributes) Then
            MyBase.Attributes = value
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

Or this other property to set the shortcut description:

```
<Description("The shortcut description.")>
<DisplayName("Description")>
<Category("Shortcut")>
Public Property Description As String
    Get
        Return Me.description_
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        If (value <> Me.description_) Then
            Me.description_ = value
            Me.WriteLink()
        End If
    End Set
End Property
Private description_ As String
```

( Note the call to `Me.WriteLink()` method, which writes modifications to the shortcut file. )

This is the behavior that I implemented because it is what I expect, it is the same as when working with a regular FileInfo/DirectoryInfo class, rather than implementing a kind of "SaveFile" method...

However, this is a special scenario on which I want to prevent this behavior, because I'm representing the class properties visually, and when I modify the value of any property in the property grid, it modifies the shortcut file, and I consider it too many unnecessary write operations to the shortcut file...

Instead, I will let the end-user to be able change any values in the user-interface without constantly re-writing the shortcut file, and just use a kind of 'Save' button to apply the changes made to the shortcut file when he is ready.

---

My question is: in C# or VB.NET, which would be a good approach to accomplish this, without modifying the implementation of my **ShortcutFileInfo** class? (the property setters). I mean, how can I let the end-user edit any property in the property grid, without firing the property setter of the loaded object?, or something else to prevent the shortcut file from being modified when a property value in the property grid is changed.

Maybe something could be done through the `PropertyGrid.PropertyValueChanged` event, but I'm not sure what, and how to.

The only and most mediocre solution I can think of, is that when I'm about to load a **ShortcutFileInfo** object in the property grid, create a copy of that object, with a path pointing to the system's temporary directory, and load that object in the PropertyGrid. This way the original shortcut file will not be modified, but the temporary shortcut file created in the system's temporary directory will be modified, so this really does not solve the main problem.

---

If helpful to understand it better, this is what I do to create a shortcut file, and load it in the property grid:

```
Dim lnk As New ShortcutFileInfo("C:\Test Shortcut.lnk")
lnk.Create()

' Deletes FileAttributes.ReadOnly attribute from file, like FileInfo class does.
lnk.IsReadOnly = False

With lnk
    .Attributes = FileAttributes.System
    .Description = "My shortcut file description"
    .Hotkey = Keys.Shift Or Keys.Alt Or Keys.Control Or Keys.F1
    .Icon = "Shell32.dll"
    .IconIndex = 0
    .Target = "C:\Target.exe"
    .TargetArguments = "/arg1 /arg2"
    .WindowState = ShortcutWindowState.Normal
    .WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(lnk.Target)
End With

' Adds FileAttributes.ReadOnly attribute to file, like FileInfo class does.
lnk.IsReadOnly = True

Me.PropertyGrid1.SelectedObject = lnk
```

Note that when any of the properties of `lnk` object are set, the shortcut file is re-written. As expected.

Comment: Why not add a method or property that denotes that you want to defer writes for now, and just have WriteLink check for this state and exit immediately without doing the thing? Obviously if it is a property you wouldn't make it browsable, but I think I'd use a method pair - a but like `SuspendLayout` / `ResumeLayout` in UI controls

Comment: @Marc Gravell thanks for answer. Yes that is a idea I had too, but see, what you suggest at the end is the same as removing the calls to WriteLink from the property setters, and just make the WriteLink method public. It's the same, expressed in other way, instead of using a property to activate or deactivate writes, just call the WriteLink method at any time. The thing is that it will drastically change the usage of this class. and my intention is to be as similar and friendly as FileInfo class usage.

Comment: Oh, you mean a non-browsable property to defer writes only for this scenario. Well, it is a solution but I prefer, if possible, a solution that does not imply to add "dummy" properties to the implementation.

Comment: Since it's your `Me.WriteLink()` (calling a Shell method?) that gets the job done, you could add a parameter (true, false) that performs the writing immediately or not based on an internal condition (a flag). If true you write, if false you don't, maybe serialize, then execute the actual write on demand.

Comment: The problem is that in order to use that flag, in some way the **ShortCutFileInfo** object should be aware about it is being loaded in the Property Grid, to set the flag to false (defer writes) for that reason... I don't think that could be possible.

Comment: @ElektroStudios actually, detecting that it is being loaded is pretty trivial; the problem is detecting when it is being *unloaded*; i.e. if you are deferring writes... when do you actually write them? (Easiest way to detect loading is to use a custom type descriptor)

Comment: If helpful to take possible ideas about how to solve this problem, I uploaded what I have in GitHub: https://github.com/ElektroStudios/Easy-Link-File-Viewer - full source-code and with the compiled exe in the Debug folder.

Comment: Then make it *aware*. Someone has to set it as the PropertyGrid's `SelectedObject`. I'ld add a property, say `.AcceptChanges`, that allows or disallows writing to the file, then set it as the `SelectedObject`. The *thing* could be more complex than that (auto-detecting when it's the `SelectedObject`), but the main functionality won't change. The class can preserve the modifications (*serializing* itself is just an example), then change the flag when saving is requested (*deserialzing* itself is just an example).

Comment: @Jimi thanks for answer. Then you guys think there is no other viable way than adding a new property in the ShortcutFileInfo class to enable/disable writes to the shortcut file on demand?. Can't this be solved by subclassing and tricking the Property Grid in some way?.

Comment: @ElektroStudios this isn't a matter for the propertygrid, although if it were: a custom type descriptor is the usual way to trick it. The grid's job is to read and write properties. It is doing its job already.

Comment: @ElektroStudios IMO you might want to think about how ORMs etc handle this scenario. They don't write to the DB every time a property changes. Instead, that is deferred with just a change tracking mechanism as the buffer, and an explicit "commit" step separately.

Comment: If you don't want to create a custom object that derives from PropertyGrid and override `OnPropertyValueSet` and friends, or use UI Automation to detect when the PropertyGrid calls the `AccessibilityObject.RaiseAutomationNotification` method (which complicates a simple buffering-matter beyond measure), I think that using a flag to determine when saving ought to be performed or not is a possible solution.

Comment: Have you dismissed @MarcGravell's recommendation of  _custom type descriptor_ based solution?  Given all your constraints, I see no other option than wrapping the instance in such a proxy class and displaying the proxy in the PropertyGrid.  It is a bit of a pain to fill-in all the necessary overrides, but overall the code is not extensive.